# Example of a Localized/Internationalized GraphQL Schema

Tags: graphql

I cannot find any examples or best practices about designing a GraphQL schema that contains localized (multilingual) text. Any ideas?

Comment: include `Accept-Language` header value in the context?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm referring to the schema design server-side, and not how the client would make the call.